# Получение некоторых параметров для AJAX-запроса

Tags: javascript, joomla

Каким образом в PHP-скрипт, вызываемый через AJAX, можно передать ID текущего материала? В дополнение к предыдущему вопросу про безопасный вызов AJAX-запросов, решил, что некоторые данные можно узнать на стороне сервера с помощью запросов к базе данных, а не передавать их с помощью JavaScript. Но для этого нужно передать некоторый набор стартовых данных, и один из них - ID текущего материала, открытого на странице. По ID материала можно узнать ID его автора, и дальше уже раскрутиться.

Вся проблема именно в этом значении. Брать его из URL с помощью JavaScript не получится, так как включен параметр SEF. Насколько допустимо взять этот параметр из заранее подготовленного div-объекта на странице при ее загрузке и затем хранить в переменной, при необходимости передавая эту переменную в AJAX-запросы? Опасно ли это, и может ли пользователь поменять значение такой переменной, как ему вздумается?

И еще волнует другой связанный вопрос. Многие действия на сайте производятся при помощи JavaScript при загрузке страницы. Например, удаляются некоторые элементы, недоступные для текущего пользователя, которые не удалось удалить другими путями (например, для их удаления пришлось бы вмешиваться в код файлов системы, что делать было нежелательно). Теоретически, могут эти элементы быть разблокированы пользователем? Например, приостановить выполнение JavaScript, убрать классы, по которым производится выбор и удаление элементов, и тем самым избежать их удаления.

Comment: Дело в том, что все что вы загрузили в браузер пользователю, может быть использовано против вас - он может получить доступ, изменить значения data-аттрибтов и т.д, бороться с этим возможно только на серверной стороне - при сохранении любых данных вы должны проверять, имеет ли пользователь возможность производить какое-либо действие с данным элементом.

Comment: По поводу передачи Id материала - это нормальная практика, только как выше сказано, проверяйте возможность редакции от этого пользователя. То-есть если он испортит свой материал - ему можно, он автор(его проблемы), если чужой, то эта - дырявая система, которая не смогла защитить автора.

Comment: Reinq, огромное спасибо за терпение, я в этом вопросе, можно сказать, совсем nup, поэтому иногда задаю кажущиеся глупыми вопросы.

Comment: Если хотите обезопасить себя от подмены id (который возвращается в ajax запросе), размещаемого на странице, то можете связать с ним хэш (md5, sha и т.п.) из него и времени формирования страницы. Пару id:hash запоминаете на сервере, а  также размещаете этот хэш на странице и он должен присутствовать в ajax запросе. При анализе запроса достаете по id запроса запомненную пару id:hash и сравниваете хэши.